# in plpgsql, how to exit from a function returning records

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

in postgresql plpgsql,

```
create function f1( p_i int ) returns table( c1 int ) as $$
begin
  -- wish to exit, do not wish to return anything
  if p_i < 0 then
     -- cannot RETURN - since can only return record!
  end if;

  -- continue processing
  return query select c2 from t1 where c1 = p_i;
  ...
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

according to [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING), the only way to break out of a function is RETURN.  but a RETURN here requires RETURN QUERY or RETURN NEXT - there seems to be no way to simply exit out of the function.

Comment: If a function (like yours) is defined to return `TABLE()` or `SETOF ...` you can simply `RETURN;`. You must be thinking of functions that return a value and have no `OUT` parameter defined. **Then** you need to return a value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `p_i < 0` is actually an error then you could [raise an exception](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html):

```
if p_i < 0 then
    raise exception 'Don''t know what to do with %', p_i
end if;
```

If `p_i < 0` should just quietly return nothing then you could do something like this:

```
create or replace function f1( p_i int ) returns table( c1 int ) as $$
begin
    if p_i < 0 then
        return;
    end if;
    return query select c2 from t1 where c1 = p_i;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN54080):

> **39.6.1.2. RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY**
>   [...]
>   the individual items to return are specified by a sequence of `RETURN NEXT` or `RETURN QUERY` commands, and then a **final `RETURN` command with no argument is used to indicate that the function has finished executing**.

Emphasis mine. So you can use your `return query` to return the query and just a simple `return;` to bail out without doing anything.

For example, the `return;` version gives me things like this:

```
=> select * from f1(-1);
 c1 
----
(0 rows)
=> select * from f1(1);
 c1 
----
  1
  1
  ...
(15 rows)
```

and the exception version does this:

```
=> select * from f1(-1);
ERROR:  Don't know what to do with -1
```

Comment: good idea for empty table.  now not returning anything at all - sort of the same as returning an empty table - and seems to work.  but just like `break` is so nice to have in a `loop`, a `return` that will exit the `function` would be nice to have.  problem is that `return` takes on two tasks: return value and exit.

Comment: @ccyoung: I was missing something obvious, you don't need the `generate_series` trick, just a simple `return;` will do.

Comment: if you do a simple `return` an error is raised: must be RETURN QUERY or RETURN NEXT.  let me check again - might have been brain dead.

Comment: you are absolutely right!  put simple return in the condition - all is well.  thanks!